# Plotting Modeled Data as my Regression Curve in R/RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two numerical data sets; one experimental, and one modeled. I have plotted the data set as a scatter plot in R. The experimental data are:

> `x=c(1.11,2.84,3.97,6.40,7.60,7.43,5.75,3.60,3.59)`
>   `y=c(0.973,0.818,0.74,0.44,0.2688,0.282,0.50,0.613,0.656)`

This is a pretty straight forward scatter plot. I also have some modeled data I acquired using an equation. This data needs to be superimposed on this plot. The modeled data is as follows:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
y = c(.994,.954,.860,.721,.570,.434,.362,.244,.185,.142,.110,.087)
```

How do I take these data, make a regression curve with them, and use them to generate some simple statistics comparing the modeled data to the experimental data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First plot line

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
y = c(.994,.954,.860,.721,.570,.434,.362,.244,.185,.142,.110,.087)
plot(x, y, type = "l")
```

Then points

```
x=c(1.11,2.84,3.97,6.40,7.60,7.43,5.75,3.60,3.59) 
y=c(0.973,0.818,0.74,0.44,0.2688,0.282,0.50,0.613,0.656)
points(x, y, col = "red")
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I generate statistics on this line? I basically just need r^2.

Comment: you should do `mod <- lm(y ~ x)` than `summary(mod)` on your data. I think you can clarify the question a bit. where do numbers for plot line come from??? I thought from the `lm` done on the raw data

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, This is exactly what I need. The data comes from a data set I uploaded to R.